# How to save int value locally in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have quantity buttons in my flutter app Plus and Minus button which increases and decreases the value by one now I want to save that value in SQLite so that even when the user closes the app and comes back the quantity value should remain the same

Comment: Hey @taha, Try uploading something you have done so it would be easy to give help from there.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to do it by SQLite since you want to save only one persisten integer value. SharedPreferences is easier for your purpose.

> SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
>       prefs.setInt("theNumberYouWantToSave", value);

Then, get the latest value by below.

> SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
>       value = prefs.getInt("theNumberYouWantToSave");

Checkout:
Take care.

Answer (score 0):

if it is the case that you only have to store just a single value..you can use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) from [pub.dev](https://pub.dev)